# grails 4, is parseRequest in url mapping not working

Tags: grails

I have parseRequest: false in my url mapping, but it still seems to parse the request.

```
"/imap/$action?/$id?"(controller:"imap", parseRequest:false)
```

The params object is still populated and the request.reader object is empty.

Basically, I'd like to populate a GrailsParameterMap myself after custom parsing the request post body in an interceptor.

When I try to do this in an interceptor though, I get a "stream closed" exception even though the parseRequest is set to false.

```
  boolean before(){
       request.getReader().text; //blows up. the request has already been parsed?
  }
```

Comment: Is the request being handled by a controller action which accepts a command object parameter?

Comment: no,  if i build my own grails parameter map, will a command object argument  act normally

Comment: "if i build my own grails parameter map, will a command object argument act normally" - The answer would depend on what you do with that map you create.  If you put it in the `DataBindingSource` that the command object data binder is using, then you would affect how the command object is dealt with. If you just create the map and interact with it yourself, that would not affect command objects.

Comment: "Basically, I'd like to populate a GrailsParameterMap myself after custom parsing the request post body in an interceptor." - If the reason you want to do that is to affect data binding, that probably isn't the best way to go about accomplishing the goal.  Is that the reason you want to do this?